# Is it possible to add computational facilities to otherwise "mathematical" formal systems by adjoining identities to types?

Tags: logic, type-theory, computer-algebra-systems, formal-systems, rewriting-systems

The following thought has been on my mind for years.

Think of $\mathbb{N}$ as the type of all well-formed expressions representing natural numbers. And think of $$\tilde{\mathbb{N}} := \frac{\mathbb{N}}{x \in \mathbb{N} \vdash x + 0 = x \mid x,y \in \mathbb{N} \vdash x + S(y) = S(x+y)}$$

as the type of all well-formed expressions representing natural numbers that have been put into normal form by repeatedly applying the identities in the denominator. There's functions $$\alpha : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \tilde{\mathbb{N}}, \qquad \beta : \tilde{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$ defined as follows: $\alpha$ turns an arbitrary well-formed expression of type $\mathbb{N}$ into a task for your computer to solve, in which the computer must repeatedly apply the rules until the expression is in normal form. And $\beta$ simply includes $\tilde{\mathbb{N}}$ into $\mathbb{N}$. To reduce an expression like $3 + 4$ to normal form, we can write $\beta(\alpha(3 + 4))$. This constructs the job $3 + 4$ for our computer (this is what $\alpha$ does), waits until the problem has been solved (this is just how the underlying computational framework operates), and then "forgets" the fact that it's now in normal form (this is what $\beta$ does). In this way, we compute $3 + 4 = 7$.

Of course, this makes no sense. You can't systematically compute $3 + 4 = 7$ without knowing a bit more. For example:

1. You also can't prove $3 + 4 = 7$ in this way without knowing $3$ is supposed to be replaced by its definition $S(S(S(0))),$ whereas $+$ is not supposed to be replaced by its definition, because after all, we're going to deal with $+$ using equations, not definitions.
2. You also can't prove $3 + 4 = 7$ unless you realize that the expression you've constructed, namely $S(S(S(S(S(S(S(0)))))))$, is supposed to be reported to the end-user as the numeral $7$.

As a result of not being able to address these issues, I find myself unable to see how one might start with a "mathematical" formal system and then adjoin computational facilities by allowing the end-user to "attach" identities to types, thereby constructing "computational types" that automatically reduce their terms to normal form.

> **Question.** Is it possible to add computational facilities to mathematical formal systems by adjoining identities to types, and if so, how are issues (1) and (2) above addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebraic theories (and their extensions) may be augmented by *rewriting rules*, like the ones you describe. For example, we could have a rule
$$\frac{\vdash n : \mathbb N \quad \vdash m : \mathbb N}{\vdash \mathsf{s\text{-}add\text{-}cong} : \mathsf{add}(\mathsf{s}(n), m) \Rightarrow \mathsf{s}(\mathsf{add}(m, n))}$$
and so on. These are studied in rewriting theory. Note that, in general, rewriting systems specified in this way may not have unique normal forms for terms: this requires proof.

There are two straightforward solutions to the problems you raise (leaving aside the question of efficiency).

1. Either new nullary operators $3$, $4$ and $7$ can be introduced into the system, and rewrites
   $$\frac{}{\vdash \mathsf{3\text{-}def} : 3 \Rightarrow \mathsf{s}(\mathsf{s}(\mathsf{s}(\mathsf{z})))}$$
   introduced to give a canonical representation (though note that such a system will not be finitely axiomatisable). Alternatively, this can simply be treated as a parsing problem, with $3$ simply being a name for $\mathsf{s}(\mathsf{s}(\mathsf{s}(\mathsf{z})))$, which is used in the input language, but which the underlying rewriting system will have no knowledge of.
2. The system dealing with the rewriting system can have pretty-printing facilities to automatically convert certain terms into canonical representations, i.e. it would convert $\mathsf{s}(\mathsf{s}(\mathsf{s}(\mathsf{z})))$ to $3$ when outputting to a user. The rewriting system itself would have no knowledge of $3$.

Thus, we can separate the question of purely formal computation and the question of concrete syntax, rather than attempting to construct a system that handles both.